# Java String from Map of X-Y Coordinates

Tags: java, string, dictionary, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I have a Map where Coords is defined as so:

```
class Coords {
        int x;
        int y;
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            Coords c = (Coords)o;
            return c.x==x && c.y==y;
        }
        public Coords(int x, int y) {
            super();
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
        public int hashCode() {
            return new Integer(x+"0"+y);
        }
    }
```

(not very good, I know, please don't tease me.)  How can I now create a String where the characters are mapped from this map, for example:

```
Map<Coords, Character> map = new HashMap<Coords, Character>();
map.put(new Coords(0,0),'H');
map.put(new Coords(1,0),'e');
map.put(new Coords(2,0),'l');
map.put(new Coords(3,0),'l');
map.put(new Coords(4,0),'o');
map.put(new Coords(6,0),'!');
map put(new Coords(6,1),'!');
somehowTransformToString(map); //Hello !
                               //      !
```

Thanks,
Isaac Waller
(note - it's not homework)

Comment: What is your output? STD console?

Comment: Actually, a text field control.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Create a comparator which can sort Coords by y and then x:

   ```
   int d = c1.y - c2.y;
   if (d == 0) d = c1.x - c2.y;
   return d;
   ```
2. Create a sorted map:

   ```
   TreeMap<Coords, Character> sortedMap = new TreeMap(comparator);
   sortedMap.putAll(map); // copy values from other map
   ```
3. Print the values of the map in order:

   ```
   for (Character c: map.values()) System.out.print(c);
   ```
4. If you need newlines:

   ```
   int y = -1;
   for (Map.Entry<Coords, Character> e: map.entrySet()) {
       if (e.y != y) {
           if (y != -1) System.out.println();
           y = e.y;
       }
       System.out.print(c);
   }
   ```

Comment: putAll(): Fixed. The comparator will first sort by Y. If Y is the same for two chars, they will be sorted by X. So I'm not sure what you mean by "This works for X".

Comment: There are no newline characters printed. This is fairly good though so I'll accept it.

Comment: In this case, keep the current Y value in a local variable and use the Entity interface of the map. When the Y value changes, print a newline.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you add a toString method to Coord or use the Point class.

```
Map<Point, Character> map = new HashMap<Point , Character>();
map.put(new Point(0,0),'H');
map.put(new Point(1,0),'e');
map.put(new Point(2,0),'l');
map.put(new Point(3,0),'l');
map.put(new Point(4,0),'o');
map.put(new Point(6,0),'!');
map put(new Point(6,1),'!');
String text = map.toString();
```

If you want to layout the characters you could use multi dimensional array.

```
char[][] grid = new char[7][2];
grid[0][0] ='H';
grid[0][1] ='e';
grid[0][2] ='l';
grid[0][3] ='l';
grid[0][4] ='o';
grid[0][6] ='!';
grid[1][6] ='!';
for(char[] line: grid) System.out.println(new String(line));
```